# Discord.js not displaying Bots custom activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been trying to add a custom status for my bot this is what I put:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`donations | ${config.prefix}donate`, { type: "WATCHING" });
});
```

Nothing is coming up when I run the bot. Did I put something wrong?

Comment: it is ok and should work

Comment: Make sure the Logged in as, is being logged to console and there is no error.
Also try to remove the ${config.prefix} to see if this is the issue.
If you see the console.log and tried without the ${config,prefix}, please tell me your node.js version, by running `npm ls discord.js`

Comment: Still does not seem to be displaying anything.( Still have not done the npm update yet will follow up)